# Neural network to determine model parameters?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to fit a curve for a function with 5 parameters ? Is this possible using neural networks in matlab ?

```
%Program Code
a=50;

xa=230;

h=65;

theta=103*pi/180;%dip

k=92;

for xi=0:10:500

    n=((xi-xa)-a*cos(theta))^2+(h-a*sin(theta))^2;

    d=((xi-xa)+a*cos(theta))^2+(h+a*sin(theta))^2

    v=k*log(n/d);


    figure(1)

    plot(xi,v,'b.')

    hold on

end
```

My objective is to match this function with the observed data which I have to get a result as shown in the picture ? [image]

Comment: You have given the problem definition in code and output nicely. However, to be a good question on Stack Overflow you need to explain what *your* problem is. Where are you stuck? What code have you tried, what went wrong? The work to solve the problem is *yours*. Stack Overflow can help, but only to show how to fix somewhere you are stuck. This site does not take homework questions and post complete solutions.

Comment: My problem was that I am trying to fit the curve using some kind of optimization technique.I wanted to know how ?

Comment: If you just put the problem definition from your class, and ask "how to solve it", then it is very hard to answer. Please add something you have tried - that may help someone find an answer for you, by fixing problems with your work. Additionally, does the solution here *have* to use neural networks, they are not an obvious fit to your problem - it is not clear whether you have decided to try them for yourself, or if it is required from the original question.